# How to extract text strings in Excel which follow specific formats

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a mixed set of item descriptions which list their ANSI Cut levels.
For example,

```
Nitrile Coated Glove, PolyKor, A4

PU Coated Glove, Knit PolyKor Blended A3

PU Coated Glove, A5, Lime w/Grey Coating
```

However the "A_" is in different places in the descriptions.
I have tried using SEARCH("A?",) however it returns the position of the first A*, which is not quite what I'm looking for.

Is there any way for me to specify on the wildcard that I am looking for a 2-character text string, starting with A and ending with one number?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try adding a `*` before and after. Like `*A?*`

Comment: If the previous gives false positives. Check this: https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/lookup/partial-match-against-numbers-with-wildcard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find position of the only pattern `A#` use formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(SEARCH("A"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A1),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Since you are not using wildcards, I'd consider using `FIND` to make it case-sensitive.